# CGI Python Script - Addition Game

Tags: python, cgi

For a class I have to create a CGI Python script that will allow the user three tries to enter their answer to an addition game that deals with numbers ranging from -50 to 50. If the user gets the answer incorrect 3 times in a row the program should add one to the total counter, and give the user a new problem. If the user gets the problem correct the program should add one to the total and correct counter, and give the user a new problem.

I have a few problems, here is my script on a web page:

http://silo.cs.indiana.edu:14544/cgi-bin/0917/dgerman

And here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random, cgi, cgitb

cgitb.enable()
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n",
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
(count, total, correct) = (0, 0, 0) 
n1 = random.randrange(-50, 50)
n2 = random.randrange(-50, 50)
answer = n1 + n2

if data.keys():
    number = data.getvalue('number')
    if data.number == answer:
        message = "You are correct!"
        total += 1
        correct += 1
    else:
        message = "Nope, please try again."
    count += 1
    total += 1      
else:
    message = "Welcome."
print """
%s <p>
<form>
What is %s + %s? Answer: <input type=text name=number> 
<input type=submit name=action value = Proceed><br>
You have %s out of %s correct! 
</form>
""" % (message, n1, n2, correct, total)
print "You have ", 3-count, " tries left!"
```

Comment: Put your code in a code block. Do this by selecting all of your code and pressing the `{}` button on the toolbar.

Comment: What are the specific problems you're encountering? We can't help you if you don't tell us what's wrong.

Comment: The program is not keeping track of how many tries the user has left correctly, and creates 2 new numbers every time the user clicks the submit button (there should only be 2 new numbers generated if the user gets the question correct, or if they get it incorrect three times in a row.)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the basic request-response nature of HTTP. You can't ask the user for input multiple times in a single CGI request, you can only take one input at the start, then return one output.

The traditional way to deal with this is to break the code up, so that each output is a web page with a form in it that calls the CGI script again (or calls a different one) with the next input, with any state (like your `answer`, `count`, and `total`) stored in hidden form variables or cookies.

The modern way to do this is to write an AJAX application that runs in the browser, with JavaScript code that keeps track of the state and makes "web service" requests and then modifies the page's DOM appropriately, instead of downloading a whole new page. But it's worth learning how to do it the CGI way first.

---

[CgiScripts](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts) on the Python wiki has a good simple example. The first time you visit the page, you aren't sending a `message` from a form, so it shows `Previous message: <no message>`, and gives you a form to enter a message, with the `submit` taking you back to the same page. Which you submit, now you *are* sending a `message`, so it shows `Previous message: My message that I typed` and then gives you the same form.

So, translate that to your problem:

The first time you visit the page, no random number will have been picked, no guesses will have been made so far, and there won't be a new guess to check, so your code will print the `Welcome` message. So far, so good. But the form you include needs to also have (hidden or visible) fields that will send back the answer, guesses, etc., so you can pull them out of the `FieldStorage` on the next request.

Having done that, when you submit, now you *are* sending all those things, so your code will display the "correct" or "nope" message. For the "nope" case, you need to again put all the correct stuff into the form for the next guess. For the "correct" case, you'll have different fields—or maybe the same fields with different values (e.g., if you set `count = 0`, and your general-purpose code crams `count` into the form, you'll get back `0` in the `FieldStorage` on the next request

---

If you're worried that this makes it too easy for users to cheat just by doing "View Source" in their browser… well, you're right. You could try to encrypt the hidden values with a key that you don't send to the client, but that can be cracked. The usual solution is to find some way to store the information on the server side, but without any local state. for example, you could create a database. When someone first connects, you create a session ID, and store it in a cookie. Now, each request they make, you can look things up in the database using the ID from their cookie to restore the state from the last request, then store the updated state before returning the next form.

---

So, how do you do hidden form fields?

In your existing code, you have an input field, `<input type=text name=number>`. This shows up as a textbox that starts empty, allows the user to type anything they want, and, when the form is submitted, sends the textbox's contents as form variable `number`, which is why your `data.getvalue('number')` can retrieve it.

If you want to pre-fill it with a value, you'd add a `value='%s'` attribute.

If you want it to not be a visible or editable field, you use `type='hidden'` instead of `type='text'`. Then, whatever value you stuck into the form will get sent back to you exactly as-is.

So, for example, if you want to preserve the `correct` value between page loads, you add this to your HTML:

```
<input type=hidden name=correct value='%s'>
```

And, of course, you fill in that `%s` with the current value of `correct`.

Then, instead of just doing `correct = 0`, you do `correct = int(data.getvalue('correct', '0'))`. So, on all requests but the first one, instead of starting over at 0, you're starting at the value of `correct` from the last time around.

(I may have gotten some of the details wrong, because it's been a long time since I wrote old-school HTML 3, with unquoted attributes and unclosed tags and the like…)

Comment: I am completely new to CGI, and really don't understand at all how it works. How do I have hidden and visible fields? And what do they mean?

Comment: @JTFarley: I can't write a tutorial for CGI as a SO answer, but if you google "CGI tutorial" or "Python CGI tutorial", you'll find dozens of options, like [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm) (not a recommendation, just the first search result…). But I can answer your question about hidden fields, at least; let me edit the answer.